# Respond with 302

Tags: c#, http, response, http-status-code-302

As part of security testing recommendation in our .NET based web application to show all post response to "302 Object Moved" instead of 200 OK.

This includes all responses in entire system. For example, if user clicked Save then we move to different screen. the Response should show "302 Object Moved" instead of 200 OK.

its ASP.NET application using c#

Any suggestions?

added below meta tags to clear the cache, still no luck

```
 <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0' />
<meta http-equiv='Pragma' content='no-store, no-cache' />
<meta http-equiv='Expires' content='Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT' />
```

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: Suggestion: don't do it? Or provide more context.... Just changing the 200 to 302 doesn't make sense.

Comment: I wonder if this would have to do with re-posting? Maybe they are trying to avoid hitting the refresh button or something of the sort?

Comment: i blocked hitting back button  .. but the requirement is whenever i saved data and redirects to new page then we should response as 302 instead of 200 OK 
                      "All post requests need to respond with “302 OBJECT MOVED"

Comment: added below code whenever user clicked back button HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
           HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "302 Found";
           HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location", "302ErrorPage.aspx");
           HttpContext.Current.Response.End();